# how to loop through every line of a text file into one variable in PHP

Tags: php, curl, for-loop

Not sure if the title is helpful.. but i'll break it down.

Basically I need to perform a curl delete against multiple objects in an API call in PHP.

To do the delete, I generally put the object name at the end of the API request URL 
`$request = "/objects/[insert object name here]"`

which is then authenticated and is deleted via CURL

`$signed_request = [authentication stuff goes here]`

then-

```
$put_response = do_delete($signed_request);

function do_delete($url, $params=array()) {

    $session = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
    return $response;
}
```

I have about 11,000 objects that I need to put into the "[insert object name here]" part. I have the list of objects in a text file, each object on a new line. apologies for being so vague.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there no way to delete multiple objects with this API? Having thousands of requests seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: unfortunately, no. just single delete is available. it will basically need to be multiple api delete calls.

Answer (score 1):

The `file` function will make it easy. It reads a file and split the lines into an array :

```
$my_objects = file ('my_file_with_objects.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($my_objects as $object) {
   $str = "....." . $object; // $object being your "[insert object name here]" part
}
```

[Read the documentation to see more examples on `file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

As suggested by @fejese, I added the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES flag to escape end lines from the result.

Comment: A word of warning might be required: the `file()` function is returning the lines as an array, but **do not trim** it. Each line will contain the line ending character which in this case could be a problem

Comment: first of all, thanks for your help everyone! such quick responses and i truly appreciate it. @clément-malet's answer did not work, but i think it's because the curl delete function doesn't seem to be firing off multiple times.

Comment: why don't you just fire the do_delete for every $object in the foreach loop instead of appending them to the $str variable?

Comment: that's what i need help with :)

Comment: @RobertFronzo I'm out of help here, cURL not being "my thing". Maybe TrainTatic should post his own answer or you should start a new question now that you know how to get your object list at least.